# Insufficients funds to Deploy Contract on Test Network

Tags: go-ethereum, gas-limit

Here are my files on github, https://github.com/ArtieLadie/gas_limit

https://github.com/ArtieLadie/gas_limit/blob/master/deploy.js sets gas limit here,

```
async function deployContract(web3, contract, sender) {
    let Voter = new web3.eth.Contract(contract.abi);
    let bytecode = '0x' + contract.evm.bytecode.object;
    let gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode});
```

This is the account I am using to deploy contract. It has 18 ether.

https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0xf8f07fc5301d4644ab33f59496a03363233b8f79

When I deploy contract, I get error,

`Failed to deploy contract: Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

I tried starting geth with

`sudo geth attach /home/solidity/.ethereum/rinkeby/geth.ipc — targetgaslimit 2000000`

but still no luck :-(

If it helps ....

1st Terminal

[image]

2nd Terminal

[image]

3rd Terminal

[image]

Comment: Maybe try using a gas limit higher than just the gasEstimate. (gasEstimate + 100000)

Comment: tried `let gasEstimate = await web3.eth.estimateGas({data: bytecode}) + 100000;`, no luck :-(

Comment: can you spare any rinkeby eth? 0x926f8E72CE94491Cafba874b4affD40C3b05a5e3 (the social media verification faucet --)

Comment: I'm not understanding .....

Comment: I'm asking you to send me eth on Rinkeby if you have enough to spare, so I can test your setup

Comment: @Marium How much is the gas estimate returned? What is the gas price used? To estimate gas for deployment is better to use `await Voter.deploy({
        data: bytecode
    })
    .estimateGas()`

Comment: ok @StevenV I'll do this (still trying to figure this out so bear with me)

Comment: @StevenV I created this account on geth terminal (when I ran those three terminals). I know the password,  but I'm not able to find keystore. How would I import this into metamask so I can send you some test ether?

Comment: @Ismael I tried `let gasEstimate = await Voter.deploy({ data: bytecode }).estimateGas();`, error persists...

Comment: @Marium How much is the gas estimate returned? What is the gas price used? I remember there was a bug in web3 that appeared to made the transaction fail if you used as gas the estimated value (it didn't fail but web3 thought so). Try with a fixed large gas value.

Comment: How to find out how much gas estimate is returned and what is used. Please assist.

Comment: @StevenV I tried `> eth.sendTransaction({from:"0xF8f07FC5301D4644Ab33F59496a03363233B8f79", to:"0x926f8E72CE94491Cafba874b4affD40C3b05a5e3", value: 6})` on the console and I get `Error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Comment: @Ismael where do I find rinkeby gas block limit? Tried google. When I try `let gasEstimate = 5000000;`, I get `Failed to deploy contract: Error: Returned error: exceeds block gas limit`. When I try `let gasEstimate = 1000000;` I get `Failed to deploy contract: Error: Returned error: insufficient funds for gas * price + value`

Comment: Are you sure you are connecting to Rinkeby? Rinkeby gas limit is 10M (see recent blocks on https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/). It should accept a gas limit of 5M. To print the gas estimate after `let gasEstimate = await ....` add `console.log(gasEstimate)`.

Comment: @Ismael Gas estimate prints `871763`. I connect to rinkeby via `geth --rinkeby --rpc --rpcapi="eth,net,web3,personal,txpool" --syncmode=light --allow-insecure-unlock`. Then I attach via, `sudo attach geth attach http://127.0.0.1:8545 `

Comment: @Ismael the correct number seems to be between 5M (exceeds gas limit) and 4M (insufficient gas)

Comment: Execute eth.blockNumber in geth console. With 1M gas it should be enough.

Comment: My guess is that there is likely a problem with your local node / how your are using `allow insecure unlock` . You get the same error when you try to send a transaction to me and when you try to deploy the contract, which makes me think this unlock action isn't working.

Comment: @steve when I try to send you 6 ether through geth (without the allow insecure unlock), I get error, `Error: no suitable peers available` even though net.peerCount outputs 4 --- for now I will see different ways to send ether to another account (it's a big learning curve but worth it!)

Comment: @Ismael eth.blockNumber outputs `5504285`